# How do I fix the ssl module for my Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: python-3.x, django, digital-ocean, pipenv

I have completed a project I have been working on for quite a while that is a Django-React app. My Django-React app only works with Python 3.6. I have been following a guide to deploy my Django-React app to a Digital Ocean droplet server. I have been following the guide found at [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04). I am using a video to guide me, so this is why this guide is using some slightly older versions of Ubuntu, etc., but this shouldn't be an issue. When I follow this guide, I come into the issue that I am automatically using the newest version of Python. It took me many hours but I was eventually able to download Python version 3.6 onto this server...

I have been able to get through most of the guide I linked. I have gotten to the point where I create my virtual environment, but in my case I use `pipenv` instead of `virtualenv` because this is what I'm used to. So I will explain my problem with the following details:

1. I enter my virtual environment with `pipenv shell`.
2. I run `django-admin` --version:
3. The command-line responds: `3.1.6`.
4. I run `python3.6 -V`:
5. The command-line responds: `Python 3.6.0`.
6. I run `python3.6 manage.py makemigrations`:
7. The server responds `Traceback (most recent call last): File "manage.py", line 11, in main from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'...  ... ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?`
8. When I try to do `pip3.6 install django` or `pip3 install django`, I get an error `WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. WARNING: Retrying...`

Why can't I see the `django` module? I've tried debugging for hours and I really can't seem to get it to be seen. My best guess is there is an issue with (possibly a combination of) either my path or the way the root and the user I'm working on are interacting.

Comment: What is your droplet operating system? Why don't you choose one that comes with Python 3.6 (such as Ubuntu 18.04?)

Comment: Oh your kidding I thought that that droplet came with 3.5 :( I'll investigate it, that will probably be the best bet for me. They don't give you permissions to change r/w/x on files so it has been impossible to do things.